# How to assign a lot of keybinds using registerKeyboardAction (maybe for loop?)

Tags: java, jbutton, keyevent, keystroke

Right now I'm using this code to achieve this:

```
    b[0].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[1].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[2].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[3].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[4].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[5].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[6].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[7].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[8].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[9].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[10].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[11].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[12].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[13].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[14].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[15].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[16].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[17].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[18].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    b[19].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

This method does work, however I would like for this to be shorter. Something like this:

```
KeyEvent[] kE=new KeyEvent[20];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        String inString="KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD"+i;
        kE[i]=new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD+i);
    }
```

Does anyone know how to achieve something like this?

Here is the full program if context helps:

```
 /*
 * Began Pre-Alpha 1.0: 1000 hours 19 Jan 2017
 * Completed Pre-Alpha 1.0: 2100 hours 19 Jan 2017
 */

package myCalc;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JButton[] b=new JButton[20];
    String[] bString={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","+","-","*","/","^","=",".","sqrt","+/-","C"};
    KeyEvent[] kE=new KeyEvent[20];
    JPanel[] row=new JPanel[6];
    boolean[] function=new boolean[5];
    JTextArea display=new JTextArea(3,20);
    Font font=new Font("Times new Roman", Font.BOLD, 32);
    GridLayout gridLayout=new GridLayout(6,5),rowLayout=new GridLayout(1,4);
    DecimalFormat dF=new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###,###,###,###,##0.##########");
    double[] temp={0,0};

    Calculator()
    {
        uiMan();
        GraphicsDevice gd = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
        int width = gd.getDisplayMode().getWidth();
        int height = gd.getDisplayMode().getHeight();
        int frameW=854, frameH=480;

        setTitle("Calculator (Pre-Alpha 1.0)");
        setSize(frameW, frameH);
        setLocation(((width/2)-(frameW/2)),((height/2)-(frameH/2)));
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(gridLayout);

        display.setEditable(false);
        display.setFont(font);

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            String inString="KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD"+i;
            kE[i]=new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD+i);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
        {
            b[i]=new JButton(bString[i]);
            b[i].setFont(font);
            b[i].addActionListener(this);
            b[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            b[i].setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        {
            row[i]=new JPanel();
            row[i].setLayout(rowLayout);
        }

        b[0].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD0, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[1].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD1, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[2].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[3].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD3, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[4].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[5].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD5, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[6].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[7].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD7, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[8].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[9].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD9, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[10].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ADD,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[11].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SUBTRACT,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[12].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_MULTIPLY,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[13].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DIVIDE,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[14].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_E, 0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[15].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[16].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DECIMAL,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[17].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[18].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        b[19].registerKeyboardAction(this, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C,0), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);

        row[0].add(display);
        row[1].add(b[14]);
        row[1].add(b[17]);
        row[1].add(b[18]);
        row[1].add(b[19]);
        row[2].add(b[7]);
        row[2].add(b[8]);
        row[2].add(b[9]);
        row[2].add(b[10]);
        row[3].add(b[4]);
        row[3].add(b[5]);
        row[3].add(b[6]);
        row[3].add(b[11]);
        row[4].add(b[1]);
        row[4].add(b[2]);
        row[4].add(b[3]);
        row[4].add(b[12]);
        row[5].add(b[0]);
        row[5].add(b[16]);
        row[5].add(b[15]);
        row[5].add(b[13]);

        for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
            add(row[i]);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public double runLogic()
    {
        try
        {
            temp[1]=Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
        {
            temp[1]=0;
        }
        double ans=0;
        if(function[0])
        {
            ans=temp[0]+temp[1];
        }
        if(function[1])
        {
            ans=temp[0]-temp[1];
        }
        if(function[2])
        {
            ans=temp[0]*temp[1];
        }
        if(function[3])
        {
            ans=temp[0]/temp[1];
        }
        if(function[4])
        {
            ans=Math.pow(temp[0], temp[1]);
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public void clearScreen()
    {
        display.setText("");
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            function[i]=false;
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
            temp[i]=0;
    }
    public void showAnswer(double answer)
    {
        clearScreen();
        display.setText(dF.format(answer));
    }

    public final void uiMan()
    {
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            if(evt.getSource()==b[i])
                display.append(bString[i]);
        if(evt.getSource()==b[16])
            display.append(bString[16]);
        for(int i=10;i<15;i++)
            if(evt.getSource()==b[i])
            {
                function[i-10]=true;
                temp[0]=Double.parseDouble(display.getText());
                display.setText("");
            }
        if(evt.getSource()==b[15])
        {
            double ans=runLogic();
            showAnswer(ans);
        }
        if(evt.getSource()==b[17])
        {
            double ans=Math.sqrt(Double.parseDouble(display.getText()));
            showAnswer(ans);
        }
        if(evt.getSource()==b[18])
        {
            String displayText=display.getText();
            if(displayText.charAt(0)=='-')
                displayText=displayText.substring(1);
            else
                displayText="-"+displayText;
            display.setText(displayText);
        }
        if(evt.getSource()==b[19])
        {
            clearScreen();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Calculator c=new Calculator();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Careful with this calculator. It is still in Pre-Alpha.");
    }
}
```